# how to get access to the fields inherited models?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

please help to solve the problem.

I have a model:

```
class UserProfile(User):            
    gender = models.ForeignKey(
        Gender,
        verbose_name='Пол',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    nickname = models.CharField(
        'Отображаемое имя',
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )   
    phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )
    skype = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )   
    other = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=False,
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='userprofile/avatar/', 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    objects = UserManager()

    @classmethod
    def get_new_authors_entries(self, cut_begin=0, cut_end=2):
        return self.objects.filter(is_active=1, is_superuser=0)[cut_begin:cut_end]
```

method get_new_authors_entries() returns the following fields:

```
[
    {
        "fields": 
            {
                "skype": "dfsdf", 
                "user_permissions": [], 
                "other": "zzzz", 
                "nickname": "\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d \u0422\u0443\u0440\u0433\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0432 \u0451\u043f\u0442\u0430", 
                "gender": 1, 
                "avatar": "", 
                "phone": "2014-0921", 
                "groups": []
            }, 

        "model": "app_accounts.userprofile", 
        "pk": 4
    }, 

    .....,
    .....,
    ....
]
```

but I need to get the values ​​of the fields: 'date_joined', 'username', 'email'

UserProfile inherited from User. and I see no reason why I can not get access to the fields: 'date_joined', 'username', 'email'

views.py(fragment):

```
new_authors = UserProfile.get_new_authors_entries(cut_begin=page_new_authors, cut_end=page_new_authors + 2)

result = serializers.serialize('json', new_authors)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not inheriting from user but instead make profile its own model that has a foreign key reference to user. Either way, the reason you're not seeing any of the user model fields is because the serializer by default does not do "deep serialization". You'll have to implement a custom serializer that serializes appropriately.

Have a look at Tom Christie's old solution if you want a place to start: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-serializers

Nowadays, much of this is wrapped into the django-rest-framework. IMHO, for simple use cases it's not too much work to just roll your own serializer using the standard json module. It also gives you complete control over the structure of your resultant json, which can be nice. Recent versions of Django even have a built JsonResponse so you can do something like the following:

```
    #at the end of your view
    import json
    response_data = json.dumps(serialize_data(user,profile))
    return JsonResponse(response_data, status=200)

def serialize_data(user, profile):

    my_dict = {
        'username': user.username,
        'date_joined': user.date_joined
        #... and so on
    }

    return my_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because this is a classmethod so it should receive cls and use cls inside instead of self.